# What is this syntax at the end of a while loop?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

In the following BASH script code:

```
while read -r line
do
    if [some_condition]; then
        do_thing1
        do_thing2
        continue
    fi
done < $SOME_VAR
```

What is the meaning of the last line? Specifically, what is being done with the value of $SOME_VAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<` is the input redirection operator, `$SOME_VAR` probably contains the name of a file.  Together, they'd cause the loop to read lines from the file.

Answer (score 2):

`<` is the shell indirection operator.  It takes the provided file, and uses it as standard input for the preceding command.  That command would be roughly analagous to:

```
cat $SOME_VAR | while read -r line; do
  if stuff; then
     consequence
  else
     otherstuff
  fi
done
```

If `SOME_VAR` were not assigned to a file in the current working directory (or the full path to a file) the shell would throw a `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: The difference comes when the file in `SOME_VAR` can't be opened for reading. With `cat "$SOME_VAR"` (note quoting BTW), `cat` will complain. With `done <"$SOME_VAR"`, the shell will complain.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answer's already covered most aspects of it. I would like to add that, to understand this syntax you should interpret the `while ... done` as a single but complex statement, and `$SOME_VAR` is fed to this statement as `stdin`. It will be consumed whenever there is a need to read from `stdin`. In this case the `read` statement. There is actually no difference with the standard `cmd <in >out` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In a very short terms, `<` redirects *file* specified to the right of the `<` symbol into `stdin` stream of whatever command or group of commands you're executing.

The `while read -r line; do...done < input.txt` is standard way to  read a file *line by line*.  While, of course, `$SOME_VAR` doesn't have to be text file - can be named pipe among other things - this is the usual way and is used to avoid problems with word splitting in shell.

Often new to shell scripting think they can do something like `for line in $(cat file.txt)` but if each line has multiple words on it separated by spaces, the for loop will be processing each word instead of each line. Something like this:

```
$ for i in $(cat input.txt); do echo "$i" ; done
one
two
three
four
```

That's not good.  By contrast, while loop lets you process whole line without issues.

```
$ while read -r line; do echo "$line" ;done < input.txt
one two
three four
```

You might be wondering why not just use `cat | while read -r line...`, but that's extra process and [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

---

Redirection into stdin stream of a loop can be done with other things as well. If you are using `bash` that supports `<<<`, you could send a string literal of text to your while loop.

```
while read -r line;do
    # do something with line
done <<< "Hello World"
```

A redundant example ? Yes, but proves the point that such syntax is more about redirecting input to while loop.

See also:

- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001